# Discord.js sending a message to every channel id stored in the database

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make a command that sends a message to every channel id stored using quick.db

```js
db.set(`channelID_${message.guıld.ıd}`, message.channel.id)
```

so this is how i would store channel id is there a possible way to send a message to every channelID stored using this i have been trying and failed

EDIT: I tried to do it using

```
const channelIDs = db.all() 
  .filter(e => e.ID.startsWith("channeltest"));

channelIDs.forEach(async (id) => {
  try {
    
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id);
    channel.send('test');
  }
});
```

getting error channel_id: Value "[object Object]" is not snowflake.

Comment: maybe store it in an array that you can then run a `forEach` loop over.

Comment: Feel free to post how you tried to send those messages. That `db.set` method looks a bit weird. I think you only set a key and no data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you have a little typo in your code. You set a key but no data. Here is my correction:

```js
db.set(`channelID_${message.guıld.ıd}`, message.channel.id)
```

I would recommend using a [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop through your database entries of channel IDs:

```js
array1.forEach(async databaseElement => {
const fetchedChannel = await client.channels.fetch('ENTER CHANNEL ID');
fetchedChannel.send('Test message. It worked!')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set an array of channel IDs as Worthy Alpaca mentioned.

```js
db.set(`channelID_${message.guild.id}`, ['859324671543153', '859320171505419'])
```

You can add new IDs later using the [`push()`](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs#push) method:

```js
db.push(`channelID_${message.guild.id}`, message.channel.id)
```

Once you've got your db set up, you can get the array of IDs using the `.get()` method and iterate over it using the `.forEach()` method. For every channel ID, you can use [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) to get the channel. It returns a promise, so you'll need to resolve it first (that's why there is that `await` keyword). Once you got a channel, you can use the [`channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method to send a message to that channel:

```js
// get the array of IDs from the database
const channelIDs = db.get(`channelID_${message.guild.id}`);

// for every ID stored, send a message
channelIDs.forEach(async (id) => {
  try {
    // fetch the channel by its ID
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(id);
    channel.send('Minus officiis dolore eveniet');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: i get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null i'm editing my question with a way i tried to do and failed

Comment: I'm not sure why you use `db.all()` and also not sure what and how you store in your database. It doesn't look like you store channel IDs in it.